# Is it possible to have a keto stew?

Tags: stews, keto

Is it possible to have a keto stew?

I would guess no since you need a starch eg a fair quantity of onions and carrots?

Is there anyway it can be accomplished?

Comment: What do you define as 'stew'?  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20958/67

Comment: I'd submit that meat cooked in water with no other ingredients could be called stew.  Maybe you can refine your question by adding some of the qualities you're looking for in a stew.

Comment: @juhasz I believe I asked a similar question before a related question before and the answer seem to be that to have a stew you need to have a starch otherwise it’s just a soup.

Comment: @JamesWilson, not everyone believes that a stew must have starch.  For example, here's a list of [Persian stews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khoresh), most of which have no, or low starch. And, or course, many "soups" have a lot of starch (chicken noodle soup, potato leek soup, pho, etc).  If you define a stew as a soupy dish with starch, that's fine, and it would be useful to include that information in the question.  That way, we;ll know that we're supposed to be suggesting ways to make your starchy stews less starchy.

Answer (score 3):

There are literally  keto stew recipes when you [search keto stew on google](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=keto%20stew).

From 
[Delish.com](https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/a30996215/keto-beef-stew-recipe/):

> When making keto stew:
>
> - choose low carb vegetables
> - replace potatoes with less starchy root vegetables
> - use onions and garlic judiciously
> - small amounts of colorful vegetables add visual appeal
> - add the vegetables at the last 40-60 minutes of cook time

Also, you can add heavy cream to your stew as the thickening element.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas

1:  It seems like garlic or onions are needed for a stew.  But some south Indian curries substitute [asafoetida](https://thespicepeople.com.au/2018/04/25/asafoetida-flavourful-substitute-garlic-onion/#:%7E:text=Small%20amounts%20of%20Asafoetida%20give,a%20cup%20of%20minced%20onion.) for garlic / onions.  Those curries are delicious.   You could look for a curry using asafoetida.

2:  I made a duck cassoulet that used unflavored gelatin as the thickener.  That would be good keto.

3:  When I tried keto, peppers did not make me break ketosis.  You would not want to slow cook peppers with the meat but you could add them at the end.

4:  Crucifers supposedly are low carb.  Broccoli did not make me break keto so probably not cauliflower either.  I would not cook those with the meat either.  Rutabegas are crucifers but I have to think they have more carbs.  They stand up to slow cooking.  I did not try those during keto.

5. No wine as cooking fluid.  Just broth.  A tablespoon of tomato paste probably would not be so much carb as to break the keto.